# Python black formatting in Foundry Code Repositories

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

Is there any way to automatically format code using the black library within Code Repositories? Is it possible to do so during development?

I have imported the black library, but I am not sure if I have to change the setup.py file in some capacity to enable the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's currently not possible. I have raised this(*) as a feature request last year to the dev team and hope they will consider to implement this. Please use your internal channels to raise this feature request with Palantir as well.

(*)

1. black auto formatting on save
2. pre-commit hook for auto-formatting
3. check that code is formatted in CI checks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about black, but if you want to have PEP8 styling in general you can enable that in your `build.gradle` file like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.palantir.conda.pep8'
```

Here is a [link](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/unit-tests/#enabling-stylechecks) to the documentation which is a little bit more in depth.